# Reshape NumPY array increasing and decreasing axes size

Tags: python, numpy

Is any possible way to reshape an array of size [129, 14] into [128, 15]?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No it’s not possible because `129 x 14 != 128 x 15` so you cannot end up with a structure that will contain the same amount of information. You can do a lot of things to go from one shape to another for example simply remove a row and add a column but you cannot make it reversible (assuming finite number types).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `np.reshape` on an array, data do not change. Element count is unchanged.
With this property in mind, you can see that 129x14!=128x15. So it's impossible without making choices i.e. adding or deleting data.